# Where is the same error coming from, performing LMER test? Data attached

Tags: r, lme4

[The dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nshgf1scl691byf/test_son2.csv?dl=0)

I am running an LMER test to see if how time duration of C2 is affected when other factors (V1, and V2) are there.
The code:

```
dd<-read.csv("D:/test_son4.csv", header = T)
```

str(dd)

```
i<- sapply(dd, is.factor)
dd [i] <- lapply(dd [i], as.character)
class(dd) 
model1<- lmer(C2 ~ Consonant*Place + (AK_kala.TextGrid| Speaker), data = dd)
```

#Changed factors to characters, kept the numerics same

#dd is a dataframe. Does it make any difference if it's a datatable or a dataframe? I have tried with both, using set DT for a datatable.

#Running the lmer test keeping Speaker as a random factor

This gives me error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :
> object 'AK_kala.TextGrid' not found

The error is always the same, no matter if I change the fixed or random factors.
There are many questions regarding the same. Double-checked if its a typo, but no. Checked if it's encoded in the same font, yes.
Could it be the different number of rows for V1, C2, V2, while I extracted the values to make the dataframe? Though I have checked, they are all 138 in number.

What is going wrong? Help, please. Thanks.

Comment: Is `"AK_kala.TextGrid"` in `names(dd)`? (Btw. you should not include a variable as random slope if it isn't also included as fixed effect.)

Comment: Here is the link to the dataset, I just checked, the one posted isn't there anymore. Apologies.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yvnivjla1hg79x/test_son4.csv?dl=0

Comment: @Roland Yes, it is in the column "Speaker". I just uploaded the dataset .

Comment: Sorry, I'm not interested in accessing dropbox. I'm also not asking about the file. I'm asking about the data.frame in R.

Comment: Your last comment is confusing. In the `lmer` formula, you can only refer to columns of a data.frame. Thus, what does 'it is in the column "Speaker"' mean here?

Comment: @Roland, Okay, no problem. As mentioned, yes, it is one of the variables in the column name "Speaker".  Could you please rephrase the second part of your comment. What exactly are you suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: If `"Speaker"` is a column name with a value `"AK_kala.TextGrid"` then the error makes perfect sense, in the formula you must use column names, not the columns values. Data.frames are R's way to implement the statistic concept of variables and observations in tabular form, the variables are the columns. And regression modelling functions model relations between variables (columns). Maybe `C2 ~ Consonant*Place + (1 | Speaker)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I somewhat understood this now. Thanks much for helping out a newbie. I did not realise this. Will get back once it is neatly performed. Thanks Roland, I understood what you mean.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, you are right. It is the names and (not) variables. However, I tried, lmer(C2 ~ Consonant*Place + (1 |Speaker ), data = dd) which gives me an error *number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: Speaker)*. Fitting the model could be a pain for someone who's new to R.

Comment: This new error means that you have more levels of `"Speaker"` than observations. Try `dd$Speaker <- droplevels(dd$Speaker)`. But you should have around  at least 20 observations per level for the fitting functions to produce meaningful results. It seems you do not have them.